# Time Duration Measure using Dimensions in SSAS

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, dimensional-modeling

One requirement of a BI project I have is to create a duration measure that shows the SLA from the start date of a case until the date of the report (SSRS report parameter). I'm trying to make this a calculated measure in the cube. Is it safe to have the datetimes in dimensions and calculate the measure this way? Is there a better way to design the dimensional model for this? I think this will become a performance issue (not sure if it's possible).

```
CREATE MEMBER MEASURES.X
as 
[DimTime].[Datetime_int_value].currentmember.value - [DimCase].[StartDate_int_value].currentmember.value
```

Comment: As you put it, you are subtracting an expression from itself. That should be 0 or null in all cases. I would suggest to review your code.

Comment: These are two different values. The subtraction result shouldn't be zero unless the query asks for the same datetime the case started.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620476/olap-cube-design-reference-for-a-it-support-business/26620540#26620540

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that.

Comment: You can easily make use of the `NOW()` function instead of going for a separate dimension just to track the current datetime(assuming thats what `[DimTime].[Datetime_int_value].currentmember.value` is doing). Also, you don't really need to put a `.VALUE`every time with a member unless the default property of a member is not it's value.

Comment: I thought of using Now() but the problem is that business wants to go back in time and compare report results with for example 5 days ago.