# OLAP cube design reference for a IT support business

Tags: ssas, olap, cube, dimensional-modeling

We are designing a dimensional model for an IT support business. There are cases (some call them tickets or incidents) with different statuses (feels like an SCD type II dimension)
We also need to consider the count of cases and SLA time duration as measures.

Before going into detailed design, I reviewed [Kimbal's data warehousing toolkit](http://www.amazon.ca/The-Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Dimensional/dp/0471200247) but couldn't find a matching business for our project. Are there any references for a dimensional model for this type of business

Comment: when I first read this question, I voted as too broad, but in retrospect I think it's a good question. Voting to re-open.

Comment: @MitchWheat I thought SO was code-specific. It's a good question but where is the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your limited information it sounds like you want to model as an **accumulating snapshot fact** (as well as a transaction table). See Insurance claim processing pipeline in Kimbal's [The Data Warehouse Toolkit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118530802).

It would only be a Type II SCD if the dimension entries were being updated, which in your described case they are not (you are updating the Fact table)